# How to solve for $\mathbf{w}$ in this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck in this problem. I don't know what to do next. The only thing that comes in my mind is to write this as M (M = order of x) equations and solve them. We have to solve for w (which is also a M dimensional vector).

[image: alt]

The answer to the problem is:

[image: alt]

where

[image: alt]

[image: alt]

P.S. The $\mathbf{w}_{MAP}$ is the MAP estimate of the $\mathbf{w}$ random variable. The solution to above equation gives $\mathbf{w}_{MAP}$.

Comment: You write that $M$ is the order of $X$, but you never say what $X$ is.

Comment: Sorry, I meant small $x_i$. It's a M dimensional vector. w is also a M dimensional vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing $(w^Tx)x$ as $x(x^Tw) = (xx^T)w$ you can write the equation as
$$-r_{dx}(N) = \lambda w - \left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i x_i^T\right) w$$
$$-r_{dx}(N) = \left(\lambda I - \sum_{i=1}^N x_i x_i^T\right) w$$
$$\left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_i x_i^T - \lambda I\right) w = r_{dx}(N)$$
$$w = \left( \sum_{i=1}^N x_i x_i^T - \lambda I\right)^{-1} r_{dx}(N)$$